# How do I return multiple objects with Neo4j and spring data?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to return a node object alongside a calculated field using this query. In theory, this should return a hash that I can access each person and count and pipe into a velocity template.

`MATCH (starter:Person {userId: {0}})<-[r:WORKS_FOR]-(n:Person) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[q:WORKS_FOR]-(p:Person) RETURN {person: n, reporteeCount: count(q)}`

I can return values in the Neo4j browser but have been unsuccessful to properly reference the return type and access the data in Java within spring-boot.

Our current configuration is using a PersonRepository to access the data and then a PersonService and PersonServiceImpl in order to pass the returned data from Neo4j to our PersonController.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is a @QueryResult annotated DTO to take your person + reporteeCount

```
@QueryResult 
class PersonWithHash {
   Person person;
   int reporteeCount;
}

// in PersonRepository
  @Query("MATCH (starter:Person {userId: {0}})<-[r:WORKS_FOR]-(n:Person) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[q:WORKS_FOR]-(p:Person) RETURN n as person, count(q) as reporteeCount")
  Collection<PersonWithHash> findBy...(String userId);
```

**note the change of the query RETURN clause**

Comment: That didn't quite seem to do it. It returns a valid object but the data inside appears to be null.

Comment: I had ti anotate the fields witg the name of the result column to get it to load the query result. Even though the variable name is the same as yhe name in the return

Comment: @MichaelHunger -- I work with Ian on the open source project (a Directory of Everything for the Enterprise). He forgot to mention we are using SpringData Neo4j version 4.0.0.M1. The docs say [@QueryResult is not yet implemented](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#_features_not_yet_included_in_milestone_1_but_that_are_on_the_roadmap)

Comment: Oh sorry, then you would probably use template.query which returns an iterable of maps

Comment: I have tried the same sort of query @Query("MATCH (bank:Bank {name:{0}})-[:EMPLOY]->(employee:Employee) RETURN bank.name as bankName , employee.name as employeeName"), however I am getting an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()

Comment: Can I use nested `@QueryResult` ? Like one queryResult object in another queryResult object ?